I am doing a registration form but in the table inside of the database the information has empty values
This is the code.
I am using just-validate because this is for a school project.
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/just-validate@2.2.0/dist/just-validate.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $fullName = isset($_POST["fullname"]) ? $_POST["fullname"] : '';
            $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : '';
            $password = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : '';
            $surname = isset($_POST["surname"]) ? $_POST["surname"] : '';
            $phone_number = isset($_POST["phone"]) ? $_POST["phone"] : '';
            
            $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $errors = array();
            
           
            
            require_once "database.php";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    array_push($errors, "Email already exists!");
                }
            } else {
                array_push($errors, "Database error: failed to prepare statement");
            }

            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>$error</div>";
                }
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, email, number, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $fullName, $surname, $email, $phone_number, $passwordHash);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>You are registered successfully.</div>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Something went wrong</div>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <form id="registrationForm" action="registration.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-btn">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" name="submits">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>
            <p>Already Registered <a href="login.php">Login Here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const validation = new JustValidate('#registrationForm');

            validation
                .addField('#fullname', [
                    {
                        rule: 'required',
                        errorMessage: 'Full Name is required',
                    },
                    {
                        rule: 'maxLength',
                        value: 15,
                        errorMessage: 'Full Name must be less than 15 characters',
                    },
                    {
                        rule: 'customRegexp',
                        value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/,
                        errorMessage: 'Full Name must contain only alphabetic characters and spaces',
                    },
                ])
                .addField('#surname', [
                    {
                        rule: 'required',
                        errorMessage: 'Surname is required',
                    },
                    {
                        rule: 'maxLength',
                        value: 15,
                        errorMessage: 'Surname must be less than 15 characters',
                    },
                    {
                        rule: 'customRegexp',
                        value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/,
                        errorMessage: 'Surname must contain only alphabetic characters and spaces',
                    },
                ])
                .addField('#email', [
                    {
                        rule: 'required',
                        errorMessage: 'Email is required',
                    },
                    {
                        rule: 'email',
                        errorMessage: 'Email is not valid',
                    },
                ])
                .addField('#phone', [
                    {
                        rule: 'required',
                        errorMessage: 'Phone number is required',
                    },
                    {
                        rule: 'customRegexp',
                        value: /^[0-9]+$/,
                        errorMessage: 'Phone number must be numeric',
                    },
                ])
                .addField('#password', [
                    {
                        rule: 'required',
                        errorMessage: 'Password is required',
                    },
                    {
                        rule: 'minLength',
                        value: 3,
                        errorMessage: 'Password must be at least 3 characters long',
                    },
                ])
                .onSuccess((event) => {
                    event.target.submit();
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I need it to get the information of the user inside the table. Thank you in advance.

Have you inspected the variables such as $fullName after posting but before inserting?

how do i do that please?

By doing some basic debugging. If you're being taught to program but not taught how to debug and fix your programs then you're only getting half a lesson

I did check and everything seems all good. Do you think there is an error with the code?

Well clearly its not OK. You'll need to debug it more closely,and ensure that php and mysqli error reporting are enabled. I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code, so maybe its some problem in the environment which causes it to fail. But we'll see after some more thorough testing (line by line if necessary)

I'm not very familiar with mysqli (I prefer PDO) but do you need to call mysqli_stmt_init() again before you run the insert query? I notice that you run it for the first query, and I wonder if it has to be done again for the second query.

I'd say it is better (as much as that can be said about anything) to assign the email column a "unique" constraint, and just attempt to insert the new row and handle the error if a duplicate is present, rather than checking first. The problem with checking first is that there is still time for another user to register between your first query and your second. You need to set it as unique so that doesn't cause a problem, so you might as well drop the first query.
